Vacuous statements as a useful convention
After reading extensively about vacuous statements, I still haven't managed to get some basic intuition. It is said that the following statement for the empty set: "All unicorns are blue" is true given that one cannot find a unicorn that isn't blue in the empty set. This deduction however assumes that the set of all unicorns isn't empty as the existence of one blue unicorn is a necessary but not sufficient condition for "all unicorns are blue".
My only conclusion is that vacuous statements are just a convention. We have conventions because they are useful. I just don't get its usefulness here.

"This deduction however assumes that the set of all unicorns isn't empty"." No, it doesn't assume that at all. It is premised on the fact that the set is empty.

@kaya3 I might not have been 100% clear there. All unicorns are blue assumes that there exists a unicorn that is blue. ∀ → ∃. Truth table: 00T,01T,10F,11T.

It doesn't assume that. It explicitly doesn't, and the deduction would fail if it did.

The convention is useful because it assigns a truth value to a statement that otherwise would be ambiguous. Of course this ambiguity exists only if you are using a theory of truth that doesn't account for the notion of nonsense. If you consider that, since unicorns don't exist,  "all unicorns" is a nonsense statement that can't be assigned a truth value one way or another, the paradox disapears.

@armand Yes. I don't account for the notion of nonsense lol

Not exactly.
If we agree that the statement "All unicorns are blue" must be parsed using the conditional as:

∀x(U(x) → B(x))

then the corresponding truth-table forces us to consider it as (vacuously) true, because for every object a that we can use to instantiate the formula: U(a) → B(a) is true, being a conditional with false antecedent.
See also What precisely is a vacuous truth? as well as How can I correct my wrong intuition that ∀x ∈ ∅:P(x) is false?

Yes I get this. I just don't see why we aren't using the following "axiom": the existence of one blue unicorn is a necessary but not sufficient condition for "all unicorns are blue".

The issue has a long history; see Existential Import: In nineteenth-century logic, the question of existential import was whether a universal proposition such as "all buttercups are blue" implies the existence of its subject, i.e. whether it implies the existential proposition "blue buttercups exist". See also Does the universal quantifier express existence?

And is existential import necessarily true?

@David - Existential import was assumed implicitly in traditional Syllogistic: the inference  from "All Men are Mortal" to "There is something that is a Man and is Mortal" was considered valid. This point of view was rejected with the birth of modern mathematical logic.

@David You might find my answer to this question helpful.

I completely agree with Mauro’s answer.
I can only add and recall: The reason for

∀x(U(x) → B(x))

to be true is the logical principle “ex falso quodlibet”.
For all x holds : U(x) is false. Hence U(x) → B(x) is true, even with an arbitrary predicate B, i.e. with any colour.

@JoWheler - "ex falso quodlibet" refers to reductio ad absurdum (see: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical/). This is not that, but simply based on the truth table of material implication. Also, if the domain is empty, then for any U: ∀x(U(x)) is true rather than false...

See John Corcoran's Ex Falso note regarding the unfortunate choice of name for Explosion: "Classically, any proposition from which every proposition follows is one from which its own negation
follows. Thus every such proposition is self-contradictory. Ostensibly, therefore, in a classical context, whoever states “from a falsehood everything follows” implies, intentionally or not, that every falsehood is a contradiction." U(x) is a predicate symbol: it cannot be false in every interpretation.

@JoWehler - My wife would say: Yes, yes, yes... I haven't had my morning coffee yet :)

It has been extensively discussed some days ago.

In my comment here I was also not correct: ex falso and reductio are two distinct moves (but it's correct that neither of those applies here). In my earlier answer (in the discussion linked to by Mauro) I did apply those names correctly :)

@mudskipper Please explain to me why the truth of "U(x)->B(x)" is not the principle ex falso quodlibet. Thanks.

Well, "ex falso quodlibet" is used to refer to the derivation of any proposition you like (quodlibet) from a contradiction (p & not p) (falso). "Falso" in this case is an unfortunate term that really refers to an absurdity (a self-contradiction). See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion

In this case we just have an antecedent (U(x) == x is an unicorn) that is never true if we quantify over all things in the world. So, just by material implication we then have that ∀x(U(x) → B(x)) is true (if the domain of x is everything in our world. (If the domain of x is empty it's also true, since ∀x(P(x)) is true for any predicate when the domain is empty, since it's equivalent (in classical logic) to "there is no x, such that not P(x)" (which is indeed true when the domain is empty).

The termiology is confusing since ⊥ is sometimes called "falsum", while it really means "absurdity"; "ex falso quodlibet" is "⊥→P" (for any P).

Classical chinese was more precise than Latin in this regard (the Mohist Cannons use 誖 bèi for "logical absurdity"). It's also more precise in distinguishing various forms of implication and negation, btw (for instance having a special term for counter-factually-implies).

@mudskipper ""ex falso quodlibet" refers to reductio ad absurdum" This is not true. - 2. "(see: plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-classical)." The SEP's article doesn't even mention reductio ad absurdum.

@Speakpigeon - Indeed. See my previous comments from more than a month ago where I pointed that out too. "reductio ad absurdum" is the reverse of "ex falso": if a statement p leads to a contradiction (q & not q) (or equivalently, if p leads to not p), then we infer not p.

The rules of logic and, for that matter, the rules of language which you are using to critisize logical rules, are conventions which we find useful in attempts to model the "real world".  You find the logic convention non-intuitive because of your foundation in the usage of "if-then" in vernacular language.  As it happens, predicate logic doesn't even NEED if-then: you could ditch the -> operator altogether and simply re-word statements involving it in terms of other operators.  Indeed, computers generally ditch basically all of the operators and reduce everything down to just the not-and operator.  if-then isn't in the system out of necessity: it's there to make the system more intuitive.
It so happens that your complaint about if-then is a situation where there's just no pleasing everyone.  Consider an alternative totally valid operator 'xor' which is like if-then but also false whenever the antecedent is false and the consequence true:
T xor T = T
T xor F = F
F xor T = F
F xor F = T
Note that this is what you seem to be expecting from if-then:  "if x is a unicorn then x is blue" - the antecedent here is FALSE for all x, which you would like to imply that this statement is FALSE for all x.
Now consider a statement like "if you give me your string cheese, I will give you a dollar".  You give me your string cheese.  I seach my pockets: it turns out that I don't have a dollar.  In an act of generosity, you tell me to keep the string cheese anyway.  I throw it on the ground: "liar!"  This demonstrates that the xor connective ALSO fails to satisfy our intuitions about if-then in natural language.  In fact, these sorts of examples will pop up no matter what convention you attempt to adopt as the truth table for if-then.  So, if you want to have "if-then" in your logical system, you'll just have to concede something w.r.t. the vernacular usage.  It may be your humble opinion that another convention is less un-intuitive than the generally accepted un-intuitive convention.  I suppose you'll have to take that up with the ghost of George Boole.

Consider the negation:

Not all unicorns are blue.

For this to be true, it would have to be the case that some unicorns aren't blue. That is false: in fact, there are no unicorns which aren't blue. So the negation of the sentence is false, therefore the original sentence is true.
The only "convention" here is that a sentence like "not all X are Y" has the same meaning as "some X aren't Y". That is a convention only in the sense that all words have agreed meanings by convention. For example, it's only by convention that "all apples are fruit" is true, because that assumes we are using the conventional meanings of the words "all", "apples", "are" and "fruit".
Of course it is possible to define a quantifier like "all" which is false when the quantified set is empty. If we call that quantifier "all*" ─ with an asterisk ─ then "all* unicorns are blue" is a false statement because there are no unicorns. It follows that "not all* X are Y" is not equivalent to "some X aren't Y", it is instead equivalent to "either some X aren't Y, or there are no X". That is a more complicated and less intuitive rule, but if you really prefer "all*", then you can rewrite statements to avoid the conventional "all" quantifier:

All* unicorns are blue, or there are no unicorns.

In terms of usefulness, neither "all" nor "all*" is more expressive, since either can be removed from a sentence by replacing it with the other plus an extra clause. Translating the other way, the false statement "all* unicorns are blue" can be written as:

All unicorns are blue, and there is at least one unicorn.

But the "all*" quantifier mainly adds extra steps to proofs where it is not in doubt that some X exist. Compare:

Hypothesis: all odd numbers are prime.
Observation: there is an odd number, 9, which is not prime.
Conclusion: the hypothesis is false; not all odd numbers are prime.

With:

Hypothesis: all* odd numbers are prime.
Observation: there is an odd number, 9, which is not prime.
Deduction: either there is an odd number which is not prime, or there are no odd numbers. (Disjunction introduction)
Conclusion: the hypothesis is false; not all* odd numbers are prime.

The extra step is formally needed because the negation of the hypothesis "all* odd numbers are prime" is "there is an odd number which is not prime, or there are no odd numbers". We observed the first part of that, but we still need to add the second part by deduction so that what we proved matches the negation of the hypothesis.


My only conclusion is that vacuous statements are just a convention.

Not quite true. It is on the surface of it a convention, among (some) academics. However, it follows logically from some basic assumptions. So, it is not just a conventions. It is can be easy to change a convention. Removing the notion of vacuous truth would be a mammoth task, on a par with the Manhattan project.

We have conventions because they are useful.

Absolutely. The question, though, is, useful to whom?

I just don't get its usefulness here.

Yes, the notion of vacuously true implications is probably not useful to you. It is not useful to me or to most people.
It is only useful to academics who call themselves "logicians", and earn a living as such, but don't know how to do formal logic without the notion of vacuous implication.

I still haven't managed to get some basic intuition.

This is the crucial fact.
Your experience is shared by very many mathematics students, which is why textbooks have come to include a specific section to try and convince students that vacuous truth is really, really, a logical notion.
This is the crucial fact because logic is cognitive capacity. We (sometimes) know of what is logical through our intuitions. Most people understand intuitively that Aristotle's syllogisms are valid. If that wasn't the case, there would simply be no formal logic. Some, perhaps most, logical truths remain beyond our understanding, but we cannot reasonably admit as a principle of formal logic that an implication is true if its antecedent is false, at least not without some clear and shared intuition that this is indeed the case. The reality, however, is that all we have are shared intuitions to the contrary (the academic literature already contains some very good examples of that).

Given that three people downvoted this answer, I'd very much like to know which assertions in it you think are false? I think that none is, and that downvotes are essentially intemperate.

Why do you think we need to have shared intuitions for a logical principle to be useful? We aren’t perfectly rational, and our brains do not have sufficient computational power to see every consequence. The “definition” of the material conditional A->B as ~A v B is very useful in connecting implicational statements to conjunctions and disjunctions. Also, vacuous truth is quite useful in set theory, wherein it can be used to define the empty set. Also, I didn’t downvote.

@PW_246 "vacuous truth is quite useful in set theory, wherein it can be used to define the empty set" Which makes it useless. The notion of empty set is nonsense. - 2. "We aren’t perfectly rational, and our brains do not have sufficient computational power to see every consequence." As so many things, you are confusing being rational and being logical.

Surely being rational is necessary for being logical, no?

Also, in what way is the empty set nonsense? If you need 500 ml of water for a recipe, you need it and nothing more. That is, the amount of water you need for the recipe less 500 ml is no water.

@PW_246 "Surely being rational is necessary for being logical, no?" Of course not, but the reverse is certainly true.

"The notion of empty set is nonsense." No it isn't. Maybe it is relative to your preconceptions about what a "set" is, but that just means you are wrong about what mathematicians mean when they say "empty set". Similarly with implication - the fact that you do not think an implication is true if its antecedent is false, simply means that you disagree with mathematicians' choice of words and notation, when they refer to the operator "not P or Q" as "implication".

If you still think that the empty set and material implication are nonsense regardless of choice of words, I suggest that you demonstrate this by contributing a proof of 0 = 1 to set.mm. It contains both of these "illogical" notions, and so it should be straightforward to derive a contradiction. (I'm guessing that you will disagree with this but I'm not sure what exactly your objection will be, which is why I'm saying it.)

@Speakpigeon how is it a non-sequitur? Do I really need to say “if you need exactly 500 ml of water for a recipe…”? Clearly 499 is too little, and 501 is too much, specifically for something like baking, if you need a real world example. It seems you’re incapable of actually ever explaining why you think something is. You just shoot from the hip at whatever fits your fancy.

@Speakpigeon I clearly meant “you need 500 mils and no more water”. If you can’t understand English, fine, but at least understand what I say now. Go make some toast with a stick of butter and tell me how it tastes.

@PW_246 "I clearly meant “you need 500 mils and no more water”" Ah, certainly not clearly, precisely. You know what you meant, but if you don't say  it, don't be surprised you sound illogical. This is funny because I can only guess what you mean by assuming that what you mean is logical because you are logical, but I can't reasonably do that because our dispute concerns logic itself. So, if you want to be understood, speak your mind. 2. "If you can’t understand English" I do, but given the absurdities you peddled as Gospel Truth I'm sure your claims are logical.

@Speakpigeon what? Are you being sarcastic or was that a typo at the end?

@pastebee "that just means you are wrong about what mathematicians mean when they say "empty set". Similarly with implication" Do you mean that if I used the phrase "a murderer" to mean "a member of a group of StackExchange users which includes pastebee", then you would agree that you are a murderer? - 2. When I discuss the notion of set or the notion of implication, I use the English language, and both notions predates what mathematicians now say they are. And what they say has zero impact on the shared notions of set and implication. - 3. I know exactly what mathematicians mean.

@PW_246 Typo, of course.

@Speakpigeon 1. Yes, by that definition I am a murderer. If you think this statement sounds ridiculous, then you have discovered why people do not usually use this definition of "murderer". 2. Well then you don't actually disagree with mathematicians on anything - when they say "empty set", they are instead using a language that borrows a lot of words from English but often uses them to refer to mathematical concepts that have little or no relation to their usual meanings. 3. You apparently think they are referring to "the shared notions of set and implication", and they aren't.

(To be clear: I don't actually think that "English mathematical jargon" is straightforwardly an entirely different language to English, but words used in mathematics definitely often have different meanings than they "normally" would. They sometimes somewhat resemble the concept they usually refer to, but not perfectly - even if a mathematical concept was first considered as an attempt to formalise an intuitive concept, like continuity or implication, the mathematical definition is what the word actually means in a mathematical context; the names are just so that we have something to call it.)

@pastebee "you disagree with mathematicians' choice of words and notation, when they refer to the operator "not P or Q" as "implication"." Nonsense. The word "implication" means the same thing to everybody. This notion of implication is intuitive and we learn the word "implication" before we attend a maths course. Whether p implies q is or isn't the same as not p or q is something else. We know what we call "the moon". Whether or not it is made of green cheese is something else. Textbooks use the word "implication" to denote the implication. but then claim wrongly that it is not p or q.

@Speakpigeon Textbooks always make a distinction between material implication and logical implication/semantic consequence.

@Speakpigeon "The word "implication" means the same thing to everybody." No, it doesn't. Mathematicians sometimes use the word "implication" to mean "not p or q".

@pastebee "No, it doesn't" Good, we disagree. I'm right, and you're wrong. - 2. "Mathematicians sometimes use the word "implication" to mean "not p or q"" Sometimes?! You mean they use the same word to mean two different things?! Whoa. You sure? So what do they mean when they don't use the word "implication" to mean "not p or q"? Just . . . something else we don't know what?

@PW_246 "distinction between material implication and logical implication/semantic consequence." Distinction without any difference as to logic.

@Speakpigeon What do you even mean? Logical implication is not an object-language operator, so it clearly doesn’t have the same logic as the material conditional.

@PW_246 1. "What do you even mean?" If there is no logical difference it must be because both are false (i.e. false models of the implication). - 2. "Logical implication/semantic consequence" Ok, so, how do you define that?

@Speakpigeon Of course there’s a difference. One is saying that if P is true, then Q is true. The other is saying that any model of P is also a model of Q.

@PW_246 "One is saying that if P is true, then Q is true. The other is saying that any model of P is also a model of Q." I didn't say there's no difference. I said there's no difference as to logic. - 2. "One is saying that if P is true, then Q is true." Which one is this one? The horseshoe not P or Q doesn't say that if P is true, then Q is true. - 3. "The other is saying that any model of P is also a model of Q." So, how do you decide that?

@Speakpigeon Material implication does mean “If P, then Q”, since so does “not-P or Q” by disjunctive syllogism. Also, what do you mean by “how do you decide that?” As in, is there a decision procedure for logical consequence? That only holds for some logics. I don’t know what else there would be for me to decide.

@PW_246 "Material implication does mean “If P, then Q”, since so does “not-P or Q” by disjunctive syllogism." This is obviously not true. 2. "That only holds for some logics" Which ones?

@speakpigeon How is it “obviously not true”? Do you mean “my gut can’t handle this, so it means it’s false”? If you need me to walk you through a step-by-step proof of it from principles you can’t get rid of, I will. I hate holding your hand while you cross the road, but for the good of this stack exchange I will. You have no place littering this stack with vitriolic drivel just because you don’t get logic.

@PW_246 "That only holds for some logics" Which ones?

@speakpgieom Specifically, Classical Propositional Logic, Intuitionistic Propostional Logic, and loads of modal logics are all decidable. Classical Logic has truth tables, Intuitionsim has sequent calculus, modal logic has refutation trees, etc.

christ what happened here

Vacuous truth is indeed strange.
Firstly, it is vital to discuss what it means to be true for a proposition. Generally, a true proposition is described as a proposition that reflects reality or the state of affairs. But let us define it a bit more precisely. It is a proposition that correctly describes the state of affairs. It is what it is, in simpler terms. I own a textbook. That proposition is true because that is simply the way things are. I own a textbook OR I am a tyrannosaurus rex. That proposition is true because one or more of its disjuncts is true. I have a head AND I have a neck. That proposition is true because both of the conjuncts are true. Those propositions are all true because they accurately describe the state of affairs. Now, IF I am asleep, THEN I am not trying to fall asleep. That is true, but less immediately obvious. That statement doesn't just mean that I am asleep AND I am not trying to fall asleep. Classical logic is rather timeless; currently, the antecedent may or may not be true, but it can only be true in conjunction with the consequent.
Consider the function f(x) = x. IF x > 0, THEN f(x) > 0. That is a good example of an implication. There is one more useful implication. IF a number is divisible by 4, THEN it is even. All numbers that are divisible by four are even, but not all even numbers are divisible by four. If an integer is even and not divisible by four, the implication sentence evaluates to F → T. An implication is sometimes seen as a promise. F → T coincides with the promise at hand and thereby it evaluates to T. This reveals the question one is to ask when trying to ascertain, whether a proposition is true: "Does the proposition contradict the state of affairs?". The antecedent's being false does not invalidate an implication; that situation is not a counterexample. A counterexample to an implication squarely displays that it is false. A counterexample to A → B is a scenario where A ∧ ¬B. Here, A fails to imply B.
Interestingly, the proposition "All unicorns are blue." actually implies that there is at least one blue unicorn if the rules of inference are applied. That can be proven to be tautological in only four lines if the domain of discourse is defined as the set of unicorns. This is because propositions are supposed to concern real, existent entities. Classical logic and its rules do not apply to statements with empty domains of discourse. Universal elimination and existential introduction are rules for any universal statement and they only work if the domain of discourse is non-empty. Nevertheless, the aforementioned proposition is true whereas the proposition that a blue unicorn exists is false as the domain is de facto empty. It should be remembered that "All unicorns are blue." is equivalent to "There does not exist a unicorn, that is not blue.". Obviously, there does not exist a unicorn that is not blue as there are no unicorns. There does not exist a unicorn that is fertile. There does not exist a unicorn that is not a tax collector. Anything goes, so to speak. The inexistence-focused version is more comprehensible. That also serves to underscore that counterexamples are paramount. Such statements make sense, but deductions with them are limited. I am not even sure if quantifier conversion can be applied in this case, but I haven't noticed any problems in doing it. As far as I can tell, quantifier conversions are entirely unrelated to the domain of discourse and solely related to the meaning of the quantifiers. Implications are much simpler.

Inexistence- and counterexample-focused reformulations of universal statements about empty sets may set things straight in that area, but it is unclear. Indeed, in classical logic a stand-alone claim such as "All unicorns are blue." implies the existence of blue unicorns and it would have to be explicitly stated that the domain of discourse is empty. No further deductions would be made and the claim would be treated as true along with its supposed equivalent that I have mentioned, which presumably relies upon rules that are not specific to classical logic.
The other area is implications, which I have already written a little about. Perhaps it is best to take care of implications by easily proving or recalling that any implication sentence is equivalent to some other sentences. Briefly, ((A → B) ⇔ (¬A ∨ B)) ∧ ((A → B) ⇔ ¬(A ∧ ¬B)). Moreover, not allowing for vacuous truth to be true would result in the negation of the Laws of Logic. It is always true that A → A. But what if A is false? The statement evaluates to F → F, which evaluates to T as it obviously should. This truth is clearly vacuous, but more intuitive than anything.





To address your point about this being a convention, it is not. At least if a convention is merely the way something is usually done. As you can see, it is as much a convention that A → B is true when it evaluates to F → T as it is a convention that ¬A ∨ B is true when it evaluates to T ∨ T.
